# What is the best method for integrating an existing database schema into a RoR migration?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, dump

So basically I have an existing dump SQL file and I need to integrate it into a new RoR project. So I want to generate the .rb schema file as well as all the classes from the model layer.

How can I do it in Rails 3?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be
alexrothenberg/legacy_data or  timriley/acts-as-importable github projects will help.

Sorry, I'm new user and can not post links.

Comment: Had to thank you one month later because the first gem is just amazing! Thanks!